# Does Mule support "-"(hyphen) in keys?

Tags: mule, mule-esb

Does Mule platform supports the "-" (hyphen) in payload keys when accessing them? If it does support can anyone provide an example or sample source for the same? I have a payload key with that special character and Mule fails to reference it directly.

Comment: This question does not make much sense. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? What problems have you encountered using hyphen and where? Mule supports any data as part of a payload.

Comment: I think u need some code sample. Below is the sample format to address my issue.
payload: {
                 sample-data:{
                                         "test":"123"
                                        }
                 }.

Now i am trying to get the value from the payload as #[payload.sample-data.test]. Then it is throwing the error at "-" saying that invalid or illegal character at this place.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot reference keys with special values directly as those special values may be reserved characters or functions. What you should do is reference them in between `'`.

In the example you mentioned, instead of referencing the "sample-data" as `#[payload.sample-data.test]` you should reference it as `#[payload.'sample-data'.test]`